# What is best practice to develop protractor tests

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I'm building protractor tests for my Angular 5 app (built with Angular CLI). My problem is that to build a test takes a lot of time - each time I run `ng e2e` I need to wait until the app is compiled. That happens lot of times, since there are lot of mistakes with incorrect selectors in my code.

I have feeling that I'm doing something wrong. There must be a way to do protractor tests faster... am I right?

Comment: E2E tests are generally slower than unit tests. If you want to avoid starting the app as part of the test run, e.g. if you're already running `ng serve` anyway, you can see how [in the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/e2e).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - looked in the docs (still not clear for me), may you please post more detailed answer -so it will be more clear ?

Comment: If your question is *"how do I stop `ng e2e` serving the app"*, that's in the docs. If it's *"how do I speed up my protractor tests"* that seems too broad, and would certainly need a [mcve] of a test in question.

Comment: my question is: is there way to run e2e without code being compiled?

Comment: Er, no, the app has to be running *somewhere* for you to run browser tests against it.

Answer (score 3):

To skip the angular application compilation process, install protractor as global:

```
    npm install -g protractor
    webdriver-manager update
```

serve the application as normal **ng serve** and run protractor inside project folder, command line:

```
    proctractor
```

Also you can modify file **package.json** in section 'scripts' adding line as:

```
    "scripts": {
       ...
       "protractor": "protractor"
    },
```

then you can run your protractor tests in other command line prompt as:

```
    npm run protractor
```

In addition: To run tests that matches specific name you can invoke:

```
    protractor --grep "test name"
```

also if you want to be more strict with test names and suite names you can use `^` and `$` with `--grep` option, but you should know: suite name and test name is concatenated with space. So to run specific tests from different suites run command as:

```
protractor --grep "^Suite name1 test name1$|^Suite name2 other test name2$"
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal. E2E tests do not need to be run at every commit.
The best is to run them before a release or tagging.
Once in place, you'll only change them when your code evolves.
On my project, they take about 3 min to pass with 80 tests.

Comment: thanks for you answer but i still think that it would be much better if you could get protractor run much faster, since all other angular-cli tools like live reload intend to save developer time

Comment: Protractor can't run faster since it has to build and launch the app. 
It will help you find regressions.

Comment: can you please share your test @Pmb , i have issues when i try to run more then 1 . thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where you have a live environment, as in a running webapp, you can set up protractor to run against the live app.  I'm in a situation where I never need to ng serve and run against the compiled app because we have multiple environments and I am not running tests against the production environment. In this situation is usually takes no time at all to develop and run tests.